# How to create a table without using methods or for-loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a 4x3 table **without** methods or for-loops.
I'd like to use what I learned in class, which is booleans, if-statements, and while-loops.

I want it so that if I input `create_table('abcdefghijkl')` it would start from the the left top most row and column and go down until the end of the column and then start again at the top of the next column and so on, like displayed below:

```
| a | e | i |

| b | f | j |

| c | g | k |

| d | h | l |
```

Below is what I have so far. It's not complete. How do I add to the function so that after 4 rows down, the string should continue to the next column starting from the top?
I'm wracking my brain over this.

All examples I can find online uses for loops and methods to create tables such as these, but I'd like to implement the while loop for this one.

Thanks in advance!

```
def create_table(table):
    t =  "" + "|" + ""
    i = 0
    while i < 12:
        t = t + " " + "|" + table[i] + " "
        i=i+1
        print(t)
    return table
```

Comment: Adding unnecessary constraints makes the problem more of a chore than a challenge. What's wrong with `for` loops? Python makes great use of them.

Comment: It's because in my class we didn't learn for loops. And my teacher wanted us to try making tables such as the above with only while-loops or if-statements.

Comment: So you should not use a for loop but it is OK for someone else to show you how to do it with a while loop?

Comment: You may want to first figure out how to print 'abcdefghijkl' as 'aeibfjcgkdhl'.  Have you learned slicing?

Comment: Yes I learned slicing..briefly. Would slicing be required to make a table such as this with the while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are printing to the terminal, you would want to think about printing each horizontal row, rather than each vertical column. Try something like:

```
table = 'abcdefghijkl'
i = 0
while i < 4:
    print("| {} | {} | {} |".format(table[i], table[i+4], table[i+8]))
    i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I noticed there is a method (.format) in your answer. Is there another way to make the table without it?

Comment: you could use `%s` instead I guess: `print("| %s | %s | %s |" % (table[i], table[i+4], table[i+8]))`. Or... you could concatenate the various pieces together: `print( "| " + table[i] + " | " + table[i+4] + " | " + table[i+8] + " |")`

Answer (score 4):

Think about it in terms of rows instead of columns. You're writing out a row at a time, not a column at a time, so look at the indices of the individual cells in the original list:

```
| 0 | 4 | 8 |

| 1 | 5 | 9 |

| 2 | 6 | 10 |

| 3 | 7 | 11 |
```

Notice each row's cells' indices differ by 4. Find a simple expression for the n<sup>th</sup> row's cells and the task will become much easier, as you'll essentially be printing out a regular table.

Comment: ah, the string I put inside the function could be a mix of letters and or numbers. So no pattern to what is inputted inside.

Comment: @muros: Right, but the concept is the same. Even though the table is vertical, you're printing rows, not columns.

Comment: Oh, thanks! This whole time I thought I had to print columns!

Answer (score 2):

You can translate most for loops to while loops with a simple recipe, so if you figure out how to do it with a for loop, then you are good to go. If you have

```
for x in s:
    {statements}
```

Make it

```
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    x = s[i]
    {statements}
    i += 1
```

It just won't work for some enumerable types that don't support length and indexing, such as generators.

Comment: In general, you can covert any for loop to a while loop, and vice versa, although the recipe isn't always as simple. In fact it's a good exercise.