# how to make a multiline loop with python 3

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I just started a programming course the other day with none whatsoever experience in coding. I'm trying to learn Python 3 and right now I'm stuck at this problem that I just can't figure out. Not sure how to search for the right answer, since I'm not sure about all the right words in english either.

What I am trying to do is a loop with the numbers 0-99.
I want the numbers to be in 10*10 rows so it would appear as they form a box, with 0 in the top left corner, and 99 in the bottom right corner. Starting with the first row being 0-9, the second row 10-19, and so on...

I have tried while loops and range and a bunch of stuff, but I just can't seem to get it to work. All help would be appreciated.

Thank you!
Sincerely / Joel

> 

Comment: This is quite straightforward with a double loop. What didn't work ?

Comment: You should post your current code so that people can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: There is a tutorial on [nested loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_nested_loops.htm) which achieves this, and also an [S.O. answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995951/how-to-create-a-table-without-using-methods-or-for-loops) that receives answers on how to achieve it without for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for row in range(0, 10):
    line = ""
    for col in range(0, 10):
        line = line + str(row*10+col) + ", "
    print(line)
```

Comment: Centralcmd almost exactly like that! The only thing that I forgot to mention is how to get the first line to be as long as the other lines. (Making bigger space between them or maybe another solution?), so it would become a more of a box with the edges straight? Almost like a square.